# error codes in information_schema

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Is there a view or table or relation in information_schema with the error codes or exception names?

My question is in STANDARD sql or in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I know that the list is in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html. But I want to know if there is inside some queriable object in the database.

Comment: By looking at all the views of *information_schema* and also the tables from *pg_catalog* (using pgAdmin 4), it doesn't seem there's such a table/view. This looks like something *hard-coded* into the different parts of the PostgreSQL C code, and not in any table, only in the docs you already found. If you need that info for one application, you can create your own table with it.